# Bower not install WordPress latest version

Tags: bower, bower-install

When I try to install WordPress using Bower

```
bower install wordpress
```

It installed version 3.9.2. But I need version 4.0 because I want to configure language before install WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Bower which specific version you would like to [install](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install):

```
bower install wordpress#4.0
```